# Question about pca proof in deeplearning by ian goodfellow

Tags: machine-learning, pca, optimization

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me with this part? I don’t understand why d vector should be eigen vector of covariance matirx of X nor the generalization part

Comment: For many more accounts of this, please search our site: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=pca+eigen*.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the questions but what i’m qurious about is why eigenvector is the argmax for ‘that specific equation’ :)